# Create table using multiple table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a table from multiple tables.

table a has list of IDs and I need count of IDs stored in table C.
[image]

Table b has list of IDs and need the count of them as well in table C.
[image]

I'm trying below but getting an error:

```
Create or replace tablec as 

select 
Count(id) as total
from table a,
select count(ref) as ref_total
from table b
```

My desired output should look like below and should be filter applied by date.

[image]

Comment: What is the error? Can you add more details about input and output table schemas?

Comment: (Line: 5, Column: 1)
Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SELECT

Comment: can you be more precise in your desired output? there is no date specified there, even though you say you'd like to filter by date.

Comment: My desired output is to have count of Ids from two different tables in a new table.

But date range is something optional. 

For date range, I'm thinking to get whole data in new table then I can run select on table C. M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a subquery for each **count** like below.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TableC AS
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM TableA) AS total,
       (SELECT COUNT(ref) FROM TableB) AS ref_total
;
```

output:

[image]

> But date range is something optional. For date range, I'm thinking to get whole data in new table then I can run select on table C

I think you can add **date** filter in **WHERE** clause of each subquery for your purpose.